# Access HBase data from Pig using HCatalog

Tags: hbase, apache-pig, hcatalog

I'm trying to load data from Pig script. The data stored in HBase and I'm able to map and create table in HCatalog. But when I try to access HCatalog table from Pig I'm getting exception as

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatStorageHandler
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getStorageHandler(HCatUtil.java:425)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getStorageHandler(HCatUtil.java:374)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.extractPartInfo(InitializeInput.java:157)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:136)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:85)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:85)
```

Any work around to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an issue in Jira about this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HCATALOG-621. 
Apply the patch provided here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12614519/HCATALOG-621.addendum.00.patch